# Combine two inner joins?

Tags: postgresql, inner-join

I have the following tables:

```
dealer
    id (PK)
car
    - id (PK)
    - dealer_id (FK)
notes
    - car_id (FK)
    - dealer_id (FK)
    - user_id (FK)
    - is_active Bool
```

I want to be able to select all dealers that I have active notes for. **Current model does not store** *dealer_id* **on notes and** *car_id* **on notes at once. It's an either or**.

I can do the queries separately:

```
select *
from dealer
inner join notes n on dealer.id = n.dealer_id and n.user_id=${userId} and n.is_active=true
```

and:

```
select *
from dealer
inner join car c on dealer.id = c.dealer_id
inner join notes n on c.id = n.car_id and n.user_id=${userId} and n.is_active=true
```

I tried to simply combine the two inner joins in the queries but then the:

```
inner join car c on dealer.id = c.dealer_id
```

would sift out what the first query would give me and so I would not get all the dealers I should be getting.

How can I write one query that gives me all the dealers I have active notes for?
I would like not to get duplicate dealers in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. What you want is called **UNION**:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM
    notes AS n
    INNER JOIN dealer AS d ON d.id = n.dealer_id
UNION
SELECT n.*
FROM
    notes AS n
    INNER JOIN car AS c ON c.id = n.car_id
    INNER JOIN dealer AS d ON d.id = c.dealer_id
```

Comment: is this going to take care duplicates?

Comment: Yes. If you want to include duplicates use **UNION ALL**